# Privacy risk in using Google APIs

Tags: privacy, google

If I use JQuery from Google APIs: http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js

Is there a privacy risk to my site? E.g. does this link enable Google to read my pages, track my site usage, etc.?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As far as tracking is concerned, this is not any different than linking to any third-party / external resource. Limiting the list to most relevant HTTP request information sent in its header that are read and can be used to track user activity by the content server:

- **Cookie** - Client software is supposed to limit cookies that the external server can retrieve to only those whose `domain` and `path` path attributes match the domain and path of the server receiving the request and have not expired. Additionally, they're limited to presence of a `secure` flag to only be accessed through a secure connection, when this flag is present in the cookie. Cookies can be read and written to, so technically Google could attach a new *tracking cookie* to its response and track user agents (web client software) this way. So far, I haven't noticed any request to write *tracking cookies*, or indeed cookies for any other purpose attached to Google server's response when requesting jQuery API. Most client software also has capability of warning users of presence of third-party cookies and/or block them, depending on client preferences. Since EU's *[cookie law](http://www.cookielaw.org/)* requires of all website operators to clearly warn of use of cookies on any pages that do so, Google can't really change their mind and all of a sudden start tracking requests by attaching a *tracking cookie* without triggering alarms.
- **Referer** - This is the address ([URL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_resource_locator)) of the web page from which the external resource was requested from. The word “referrer” is misspelled in the RFC as well as in most implementations. There is really absolutely nothing stopping Google to use this data for statistical / tracking purposes, as it's a part of the standard HTTP request. While this *referer* information in the HTTP request could be removed (or changed to non-disclosing URL) by redirecting requests at the server linking to Google's external resource, or by other means of *anonymizing* external requests, not many web servers actually do so. The information is hardly critical on its own, but could be linked with other HTTP request data to identify request originating client more precisely.
- **User-Agent** - This request field identifies the client software through the use of a [user agent string](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_agent_string#User_agent_identification). They would usually contain all kinds of information about your client software and its capabilities (browser type, browser version, extensions, operating system, operating system's version, libraries used by the web client,...) and can be used to identify a unique web client to a varying degree. See for example the [Panopticlick](https://panopticlick.eff.org/) project and test your browser how unique it is among all that were so far tested. `User-Agent` can of course be changed by the client software to contain less identifying information (something e.g. [TOR browser](https://www.torproject.org/) does on each "change identity" user's request), but most users would be unaware of how well their browsing habits can be identified by this HTTP request field alone, and of course do nothing about it. Google can use this information to identify web clients more uniquely and/or for other statistical purposes. This is something you as a publisher linking to an external resource can't control (it is attached to the request headers on client's end and the HTTP GET request to the external resources linked within your documents is not handled in any way by your own web server).
- **IP address** - Not really a part of the *standard* HTTP request header, but of a [TCP/IP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_Control_Protocol) request itself (transport protocol level), this address uniquely identifies the request originating network client so the response can be sent to its intended recipient. There are ways to bypass this identification through the use of the IP address by using various [Proxy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_server) or [VPN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_private_network) solutions. Not all of them will be as effective though, and some proxies will attach additional headers to the HTTP requests (such as [`X-Forwarded-For`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X-Forwarded-For)) that can lead to revealing request originating IP address, or that a Proxy server was used (e.g. `Via`) to retrieve server's HTTP response.

All the possible HTTP request header information is listed in [this Wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_header_fields#Requests), some of them could be used to track  fingerprint individual web clients, while most are actually benign in this sense and would remain more or less the same for all web clients, and are thus useless for identification purposes.

It does get slightly better though. Since you're linking to Google API as an external resource via your [DOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_Object_Model), the client software parsing its contents and generating external requests will use a [GET method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol#Request_methods) to retrive its contents, so none of the data that are a part of [POST method's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POST_%28HTTP%29) body (such as form data) can be read through such request, regardless of what HTTP request method was used to fetch contents of your document that links to this external resource.

This might or mightn't be a good news though. If you, for example, authorize users through the use of a session token passed to the server via [URI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_resource_identifier) field value to access resources on your server, you don't use [HTTPS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_Secure) on your server, and you link to the jQuery API using protocol-less URL starting with `//`, these URI fields will be repeated in the "referer" string and Google will see them in requests to their server. In other cases (you use HTTPS, or authenticate via a POST request and write session tokens to clients using cookies / user storage / session storage), this "referer" information won't be included in GET requests (HTTP *body* fields used in POST method don't leak into HTTP *header* fields on new requests), or none of the user data will be leaked through it (HTTPS protocol does not include "referer" information in requests to external resources, no matter what protocol they're served through).

As for the other part of your question - **does this link enable Google to read my pages** - well yes, of course it would be possible. Basically, what you're enabling by willingly linking to an external resource you don't have control over is [XSS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting) type attacks and, technically, Google could easily take over your web pages where you're linking to this jQuery API and completely change them to their liking. They won't do that though, as it would pretty much spell *game over* for them. Any changes to these libraries Google helps publish are also relatively easy to track by comparing received files that Google publishes to those published on the official jQuery pages, either by calculating [MAC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_authentication_code) signature of the received file and check its data integrity and authenticity against MAC signatures of files on the [jQuery pages](http://jquery.com/download/), or simply comparing files line by line.

So in short, yes it is possible that Google is tracking users' browsing habits through inspecting HTTP and TCP/IP request values associated with requesting external resource such as jQuery API Google helps publish on its servers, but if they're doing that, they aren't resorting to *active tracking* by attaching *tracking cookies* to their responses. That will limit their ability to successfully / uniquely identify web clients for any other than statistical purposes. There is no bypassing this short of web clients using TOR / Proxy / VPN servers, or you publishing jQuery API on your own server. Changing this API to include malicious code is however nigh impossible without detection, and would spell disaster for Google's reputation.

Do mind though, that we haven't really excluded any [MiTM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man-in-the-middle_attack) attacks here, where such linking to external resources does provide for *an added bonus* to a would-be attacker, that could simply substitute any such request with a location of attacker's choosing and use it as a malicious payload vehicle.

Your best bet in thwarting such threats described would be to simply publish jQuery API on your own server(s). It does come with a bit of cost to each of your users' requests, namely one more request your web server has to handle and adds to the bandwidth needed to serve requests, but it will remove all the risks described, no matter how plausible they might be.

Comment: They can uniquely identify clients even without the need for active tracking. There's a demo of that at https://panopticlick.eff.org/ - it's very basic, but still makes all browsers I tried come out unique. If you read their whitepaper you'll see that real-life fingerprinting solutions are much more advanced.

Comment: I meant active in a sense that they'd actually write to the client in a form of a tracking cookie. And PanoptiClick also collects quite some information by reading it with JavaScript when enabled (for example loaded plugins, installed fonts,... each helping identify a unique client) , something that's not quite possible here, without substantially changing the jQuery code, which of course is easily detectable. Google can only track users through GET request headers, all which can be quite easily checked - press `CTRL+SHIFT+J` in Chrome, and inspect sent headers for the external API request. ;)

Comment: @Shnatsel - And for what it's worth, I've already mentioned Panopticlick in my answer. ;)

Answer (score 14):

Technically, yes, Google *could* do a lot of this. Namely, when you "use JQuery" in your site, you actually mean that the pages of your site reference that piece of Javascript, and whoever browses your site will automatically download it from Google's servers, allowing Google to easily know who downloads it, when, and in which site the link was found (because of the `Referer` header). This is easy to do, undetectable on your side, so one should assume that Google does it (if they are up to their reputation, that is).

*Reading* your pages is another matter. They *could* play nasty tricks by modifying the contents of that `jquery.min.js` file, in order to do various things with your site pages, including reading parts of it and sending them back to some server. However, this would entail a risk of detection, since that would be an **active** attack. Google's motto is "don't be evil" and they can maintain it only on the condition that they never *look* evil. Indulging in active attacks could seriously damage their image, and I doubt they would risk that for something as trivial as reading back your Web site (well, I don't know what your Web site does, but I doubt that what it contains would match the [net worth of Google itself](http://celebsnetworth.net/google-net-worth/) -- I hope you won't feel offended at the comparison).

Comment: "including reading parts of it and sending them back to some server" -- They don't need to do this through jquery, they have web crawlers already doing it constantly. In fact, there's a whole sub-market around getting them to do so as rapidly and thoroughly as possible: we call it SEO :)

Comment: I mean that if the page is protected (e.g. with a password) then Google's crawler won't be able to access it from the outside. However, if the page includes jQuery, then a maliciously altered jQuery.js could read the page contents (by virtue of being, as it were, _included_ in the page).